# Cast pointer to a number

Tags: c++, gcc, casting

I am trying to cross-compile some code in gcc and am running into the following issue. A library wants to treat a pointer as a number and gcc is complaining with the [-fpermissive] flag. Let me show some simplified code to explain.

```
void fun(U32 var)
{...}

typedef struct
{
    U16 var0;
    U16 reserved0;
    U16 var1;
    U16 reserved1;
} Str_t;

Str_t structBase;
Str_t* structVar = &structBase;

fun(U32(&structVar->var1));
```

gcc output:
error: cast from U16* to U32 loses precision [-fpermissive]

---

The strange bit of code where I am defining a  pointing for seemily no reason is  to mock a line in a header file like:

```
#define structVar        (Str_t* PERIPH_BASE_ADDR)
```

The #define is from a different part of the library, and is casting a static memory location. The target is a microcontroller and this type of thing is common for that type of target. I know that this is a non-standard thing to do, but the library that is asking me to do this is required for my project. What is my best option in this situation?

---edit
The basic problem that I am having is that my original target is a 32bit microcontroller and my second target is a 64bit PC. Of of the challenges here is that microcontrollers are often resource constrained. Using std libs is not always a good idea here.

Comment: If you have `uintptr_t` cast to it. Otherwise implementation-defined stuff will work.

Comment: how will that declaration even compile with structVar defined as such?

Comment: The error message is quite clear: the type casted to has too few bits. So assuming the compiler is right, evidently either `U32` is misleading, or you're compiling for 64-bit code.

Comment: This may be an issue with two different targets. Target 1 is a 32bit microcontroller (does compile). Target 2 is my PC, compiling with gcc in 64bit Cygwin (does not compile). How would I get both to compile?

Comment: You are casting a pointer (`U16*`) to `U32`. This means, you are compiling for a target, where a pointer is larger than 32 bits, and the compiler is right in issuing a warning.

Comment: @Napthali compile in 32 bit mode. It is clear that library you are using does not support 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to pass the offset of a member?

If so, the portable (and correct) way to do it is with `offsetof`

e.g.:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

void fun(std::uint32_t var)  // int would be perfectly acceptable here
{}

typedef struct
{
    std::uint16_t var0;
    std::uint16_t reserved0;
    std::uint16_t var1;
    std::uint16_t reserved1;
} Str_t;

Str_t structBase;
Str_t* structVar = &structBase;

int main()
{
    fun(offsetof(Str_t, var1)); 
}
```

otherwise, if you're looking to pass an address, pass an address:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

void fun(std::uint16_t* var)
{}

typedef struct
{
    std::uint16_t var0;
    std::uint16_t reserved0;
    std::uint16_t var1;
    std::uint16_t reserved1;
} Str_t;

Str_t structBase;
Str_t* structVar = &structBase;

int main()
{
    fun(std::addressof(structVar->var0)); 
}
```

Comment: (See Edit) Unfortunately, to get the code to compile for both targets, I don't want to use std libs. It tends to be either too big or too slow for my microcontroller target.

Comment: @Napthali `offsetoff` is usually implemented as a macro. The implementation is required to make it do the right thing without warnings. There will be no overhead.